# How do I tackle this integral: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty k\cdot |Ae^{-a|k-k_0|}|^2dk$? Is my solution correct?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty k\cdot |Ae^{-a|k-k_0|}|^2dk$$

I did the following:
Substitute $\gamma(k) = k-k_0 \Leftrightarrow k = \gamma + k_0;~\gamma(\pm\infty) = \pm\infty;~d\gamma = dk$ and factoring out constants:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty k\cdot |Ae^{-a|k-k_0|}|^2dk = |A|^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\gamma + k_0)|e^{-2a|\gamma|}|d\gamma$$

Now one can split the integral and leave out the "||" for the $\exp$ since its always positive:

$$\Rightarrow |A|^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \gamma e^{-2a|\gamma|}d\gamma   + |A|^2k_0\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2a|\gamma|}d\gamma$$

Evaluating the right integral first:

$$|A|^2k_0\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2a|\gamma|}d\gamma = |A|^2k_0\left[\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{2a\gamma} d\gamma + \int_{0}^\infty e^{-2a\gamma} d\gamma\right] $$

$$|A|^2k_0 \left[ \frac{1}{2a} \left. e^{2a\gamma}  \right\rvert_{-\infty}^0 -  \frac{1}{2a} \left. e^{-2a\gamma}  \right\rvert_{0}^\infty \right] = |A|^2k_0 \left[ \frac{1}{2a} +  \frac{1}{2a} \right] = \frac{|A|^2k_0}{a}$$

Evaluating the left integral:

$$|A|^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \gamma e^{-2a|\gamma|}d\gamma = |A|^2\left[ \int_{-\infty}^0\gamma e^{2a\gamma}d\gamma + \int_{0}^\infty \gamma e^{-2a\gamma} d\gamma \right]$$

Using integration by parts choosing $u = \gamma \Rightarrow u' = 1$ and $v' = e^{\pm 2a\gamma} \Rightarrow v = \frac{1}{\pm 2a}e^{\pm 2a\gamma}$ we get:

$$\int_{-\infty}^0\gamma e^{2a\gamma}d\gamma = \left. \frac{1}{2a} \gamma e^{2a\gamma}  \right\rvert_{-\infty}^0 - \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{2a} e^{2a\gamma} d\gamma = -\frac{1}{4a^2} \left. e^{2a\gamma}  \right\rvert_{-\infty}^0 = -\frac{1}{4a^2} $$

Analog for the second term this leads to

$$\int_{0}^\infty \gamma e^{-2a\gamma} d\gamma  = \frac{1}{4a^2}$$

So that

$$|A|^2\left[ \int_{-\infty}^0\gamma e^{2a\gamma}d\gamma + \int_{0}^\infty \gamma e^{-2a\gamma} d\gamma \right] = |A|^2 \left[-\frac{1}{4a^2} + \frac{1}{4a^2} \right] = 0$$

And thus finally

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty k\cdot |Ae^{-a|k-k_0|}|^2dk = \frac{|A|^2k_0}{a}$$

I just want to know whether there is some error in my calculations :)

Comment: So your question is...?

Comment: Hahaha I kinda forgot that after so much latex... one sec

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't spot one, but lemme read it a second time.